# Hide id while show data from database in select option

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Look at picture above. "2" is an id of "fsdfs". I need the id to process it in backend. But in frontend, i don't want to show the id in that select option. Is there any way to make it real?

Here's my currect code:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplier_id">Supplier</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier_id">
            <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM supplier ORDER BY id ASC");
                while($supplier = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
             ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $supplier['id'].' - '.$supplier['name']; ?>"><?php echo $supplier['id'].' - '.$supplier['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove between the option tag, the code: $supplier['id'].' - '.  Just keep the ID in the value. Should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$supplier['id']` as `value` (which will be sent when submitting the form) and `$supplier['name']` as the text content of your `<option>`:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplier_id">Supplier</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier_id" id="supplier_id">
            <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM supplier ORDER BY id ASC");
                while($supplier = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
             ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $supplier['id']; ?>"><?php echo $supplier['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

More on `<option>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Sidenote: the `for` attribute of a `<label>` element should point to the `id` attribute of the related `<input>`. I added `id="supplier_id"` to your `<select>` to make it valid.

Comment: how can i get that id in that value to insert it to the database? is it possible if i use ```$_POST['id'];``` ?

Comment: You get the value by targeting the `name` attribute of the `<select>` that sent the value, so `$_POST['supplier_id']`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php